# Trying to find amount of <div> classes in a fieldset, if true enable button

Tags: jquery

Trying to search for a specific amount of class ".good", if not found disables button and if it finds that amount remove disabled. Can't quite get it there and working.

```
    $("fieldset.first").children().find('.good')[4](function(){
    // or maybe -- $('fieldset:first-of-type').children('.good).length !== 4?
      $('.next').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
      $('.next').prop('disabled', true);
    }
```

Or, if there is a better way of doing it, I'm all ears.

UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/aUKhN/27/

This is how the validation works:

```
<!-- when page loads -->
<div class="item"><input required></div>

<!-- if it doesn't validate -->
<div class="item bad">
  <input required>
  <div class="alert">why it isn't validating</div>
</div>

<!--  and if it does validate it changes to -->
<div class="item good"><input required></div>
```

added HTML

```
    <fieldset class="first">
  <legend>Create your login credentials</legend>
  <div class="item">
    <label>
      <span>Email Address</span>
      <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="e.g. name@email.com" required>
    </label>
    <div class="tooltip help">
      <span>?</span>
      <div class="help-content">
        <b></b>
        <p>You will use your email address to login to your WiseBanyan account</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label>
      <span>Confirm email</span>
      <input type="email" name="confirmUsername" data-validate-linked="username" placeholder="e.g. name@email.com" autocomplete="off" required>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label>
      <span>Password</span>
      <input type="password" name="password" data-validate-length-range="8" minlength="8" autocomplete="off" required>
    </label>
    <div class="tooltip help">
      <span>?</span>
      <div class="help-content">
        <b></b>
        <p>Minimum of 8 characters.</p>
        <p>Must contain at least one uppercase letter and one number or symbol.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label>
      <span>Confirm password</span>
      <input type="password" name="confirmPassword"  data-validate-length-range="8" minlength="8" data-validate-linked="password" required>
    </label>
  </div>
<div class="details">
  <strong>Information</strong>
  <p>Type in the login information you would like. Hover over the &nbsp;<span class="ques">?</span> for further information on restrictions.</p>
</div>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" disabled>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next">
```

Comment: Your commented out code looks right, hard to tell without seeing the HTML structure tho.

Comment: Do you have multiple `.next` associated to each child of `$("fieldset.first")`? and want to disable only those `.next`?

Comment: I have one .next per fieldset, only want to disable it (.next leads to next fieldset), about 5 fieldsets. Updated question with more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function enabler() {
    var v = this.value;
    var good = $("fieldset").find('.good');
    console.log(good.length);
    if (good.length > 2) {
        // or maybe -- $('fieldset:first-of-type').children('.good).length !== 4?
        $('.next').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('.next').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
enabler();
$('input[required]').not('.unused').keyup(function(){setTimeout(enabler,500)}).change();
```

### Fiddle

**EDIT:**

I think part of your problem is that the validator ads a class after this code `$("fieldset").find('.good');`. If I add a 500ms delay it works... so keep that delay, or add the `enabler();` function call in the validator.

Comment: the update doesn't disabled the button as your first edition did. But I can work with this. let me play with it a bit. I'm shaky on jquery, so the code probably has numerous flaws.

Comment: @darcher, I think the if statement in my code should be `> 4`, then it will disable=true by default

Comment: This actually disables it now, but still not able to enable the .next button once those 4 ".good" fields are met.

Comment: @darcher, do you have a live link?

Comment: it's in localhost. http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/aUKhN/32/ here's a current setup. I explained in detail in my comment in PSL's answer.

Comment: @darcher, sorry, I was away. Check my updated answer, the demo and the edit.

Comment: no worries at all, I marked it correctly because it met the needs very well, I adjusted it a little bit, but am running into an issue where it still reads the initial fieldset preset number of "4" check fiddle if you get the chance.

http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/aUKhN/33/

Comment: @darcher, what do you mean by it still reads the initial fieldset preset number of "4" ?

Comment: I still looks for the initial fieldset "good" required amount. It is calling from the class name of the fieldset now to get the required amount. e.g. fielset 1 needs 4 .good to enable .next, fieldset 2 needs 1 to enable .next, it's still saying it requires "4" on the 2nd fieldset.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/aUKhN/34/ updated wrong enabler #, but like I said, this is past the original question, so only if you hvae time to look into it, I'd appreciate but it isn't necessary.

Comment: @darcher, is there any pattern to follow? is the class `f_11` related to the number of inputs? or check the fieldset > input > length as a variable in the `if (good.length > 2) {` ?

Comment: That's exactly it, fieldset 1 needs to pass 4 ".good" classes, like the initial function you placed if (good.length > 3) { for "4" .good's. but I adjusted it to class f_11 is = to the number of .good that is required for that fieldset, and each fieldset class has the number required specific to it in the class name.

Comment: @darcher, ok. Try to use this new variable in the if: `var x = $("fieldset").attr("class").split('f_')[1];;`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
  $('.next').prop('disabled', $("fieldset.first").find('.good').length < 4);
```

Do not mix `removeAttr` and prop. Instead just use `prop` itself. You are using `find` on children, instead you can use just `find('.good')` on parent unless you want to specifically avoid finding any `.good` which is directly under `$("fieldset.first")`

Since you need to look at each fieldset and disable the respective buttons do:

```
$('fieldset').find('.next').prop('disabled', function () { //give the common class for fieldset if needed
    return $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.good').length < 4;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation +1 because of that. I'll play with it and see what I can come to. Also, updated question.

Comment: @darcher Do you have all the fieldset on the same page if thats the case `.next` will select all of them.. You need to select the specific one...

Comment: Yes, yes I do. There are about 5 fieldsets each with one .next button, I'm trying to make a function for each, originally I was trying to do one function for the whole page, now for more ease (and for a few reasons) I'm doing one function per fieldset.

Comment: @darcher Yuo need to probably try this way assuming this is how it happens.. http://jsfiddle.net/9mKxp/

Comment: I just setup a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/aUKhN/27/

But I'll test that method

Comment: @darcher try this, updated in your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/PGqyh/ Add valid data and see

Comment: still not quite getting it to enable the button when those 4 ".good" fields are met.

Comment: @darcher when will it be met, on page load? did you check if this code is run? You need to run the code after validation.

Comment: now that you say that I may have not explained this well. Not even sure if it's possible anymore. Since it's a live validation, I'm trying to get the ".next" to activate when the fields are all listed at "good", the current setup is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/aUKhN/32/ where if all bad classes are gone, it enables the button, but I'm trying to get it to read when all the div's are "good" it enables the button, that way it's on keyup insted of onBlur.